# Define the variable and equation for the situation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Walmart has a bike on sale for $$150. The sign next to it says that the price is $25 off the original price. What is the original price? Define the variable and equation for the situation. Solve the equation.**

---

This question is from my son's Math test. His answer is as follows:

Let x = original price
$x = 150 + 25$;  $x = 175$.

His teacher marked it as wrong and rewrote the equation as $x - 25 = 150$ ; $x= 175$.

I don't see how the equation my son wrote is wrong? Could you please help me understand?

Comment: The two are equivalent. Your teacher is discouraging thought in favor of process and pedantry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a minor detail: Let $x$ be the price, as above. Then it is known that $\$ 25$ is taken off, and the price is now $150$. So it must be that $x - 25 = 150$, and consequently, $x = 175$.

The distinction is that your son has jumped a step in the reasoning. You do know at the very beginning of the problem that $x = 25 + 150$, you only know that $x - 25 = 150$.

I hope this helps.